# Default error handler in angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am curious how do you guys make default error handler for all $resource service calls in your angularJS apps? Apparently it does not make sense to have a faulty function callback to be supplied for the promise `.then(success, faulure)` all the time if it is always the same. So the question is:

- do you use some kind of a default error handler for all resource service calls? how do you make it? Interceptors?
- what if you need to make custom error handler for one specific service call, say, one out of hundred, then how do you override interceptor's default error handler?

Answer (score 0):

I prefer using an HTTP service interceptor for my API error cases. It is a pretty easy thing to set up.

What does it do? As the name says it intercepts each response which is going through the HTTP service and respectively the Resource service.

My approach consists of two parts.

First the `ResponseHandler` factory:

```
app.factory('ResponseHandler', responseHandler);

responseHandler.$inject = ['$q', '$log'];

function responseHandler ($q, $log) {
    return {
        response: responseHandler,
        responseError: responseErrorHandler
    };

    function responseHandler (response) {
        $log.info('HTTP response ', response);

        // success cases go through here

        return response;
    }

    function responseErrorHandler (rejection) {
        $log.error('HTTP error ', rejection);

        // error cases go through here

        return $q.reject(rejection);
    }
}
```

and the second part, the actual "activation" of the `ResponseHandler` in the HTTP provider:

```
app.config(errorInterceptor);

errorInterceptor.$inject = ['$httpProvider']

function errorInterceptor ($httpProvider) {
    $httpProvider.interceptors.push('ResponseHandler');
}
```

I hope this little example makes it clear how to integrate it into an angular app. In my case for example I handle most of the error cases directly in the `responseErrorHandler` by notify the whole app with toasts.

I mostly rely on the error status (e.g. 401 or 403) to make special actions. I don't know if you need more, but I would suggest you "play" around with status codes and response format.

**For example:** If you have an server-side validation error in a form, you probably don't want to treat this at this fundamental level. So I send a special validation error with status code 200 which is going through the interceptor but is then caught as usual in a `.then(..)`.

Comment: Thanks for the response. The main question here is how to turn interceptor on for all of the responses and how to switch if off for certain ones. I do not like your idea sending 200 status code for errors, because in this case your backend relies on the architecture of your frontend, which is wrong by design.

Comment: Maybe there is an example needed. In my case there are some errors like I described which are different to general API errors.I thought you might be in a similar situation where this coupling makes sense. What I ultimately wanted to show is that you can make any condition in the errorInterceptor where you just let the response through so it's in fact switched off.